# html-element attributes, custom HtmlHelper.xxxxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, html-helper

I have created a simple method that extends the HtmlHelper.. basically its the TextBoxFor-method but abit customized to fit my purpose abit better.. anyway.. I think the way that the HtmlHelper uses the new { @attributename = "attributevalue" } thingy to create html-element attributes is really neat.. so my question is.. how would I be able to do the same thing?

ViewCode:

```
@Html.DaisyTextBoxFor(model => model.Text, new { @class="asd" })
```

HelperCode:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DaisyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string,object> attributes = null)
    {
        var value = ((PropertyViewModelProperty)htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.GetType().GetProperty(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)).GetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, null)).Value;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" />", CreateForInputName(typeof(TModel), htmlHelper), value));
    }

    private static string CreateForInputName(Type model,HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(model.AssemblyQualifiedName + "_" + htmlHelper.ViewData["propertyName"].ToString() + '_' + htmlHelper.ViewData["propertyGuid"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: The `RouteValueDictionary` has a constructor that takes an `object` as a parameter. Use it with an anonymous object. This can be used with p.e. the `TagBuilder`'s `MergeAttributes`

Comment: Could you please give me a code example, I dont quite get how Im supposed to use the RouteValueDictionary as a parameter for the method..

Comment: aa geat now I get it :), Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but wouldn't the below thing work?

```
public static MvcHtmlString DaisyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string,object> attributes = null)
    {
        var value = ((PropertyViewModelProperty)htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.GetType().GetProperty(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)).GetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model, null)).Value;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" class=\"{2}\" />", CreateForInputName(typeof(TModel), htmlHelper), value, attributes["class"]));
    }
```

Notice the `class={2}` part in `MvcHtmlString.Create` part.